# Trouble with Auto-Layout

Tags: xcode, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Xcode 5

I'm trying to learn the auto-layout system. Thought I would start with something simple, but I'm already getting stumped :-)

Scene: Main View -> ImageView -> View

I want to support rotation such that the Image rotates and centers on the screen, using Aspect-Fit content.

I want the smaller view to maintain it's relative position to the top edge of the UIimage view. It does't seem to understand the aspect-fit, and it aligns the sub view along the top of the main view, not the fitted image.

I think it has something to do with the fact that the small view is a sibling of the Image, and not a sub-view. I can only seem to create constraints to the superview.

[image: All good in landscape].
[image: What I get when rotate to portrait]
[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't started with something simple!

An aspect fitted image view doesn't actually change its size under auto layout depending on the image, it *fits the image into the bounds that the constraints have determined*, leaving the rest of its frame blank. If you set a border or background colour on the image view you will see this.

To achieve the effect you're after you would need to do the aspect fitting calculation yourself and modify the sizing constraints on the image view appropriately.

Comment: I had a sinking suspicion that's what was happening. Oh well, thanks for confirming.  I'll do this one by hand, and use another project to gain some auto-layout expertise. Thanks!.